# Issue with ActionTypes.MessageBack in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using 3.11 version of Bot Builder with C#. I have an action button of type ActionTypes.MessageBack with below attributes.

```
cardActions.Add(new CardAction()
{
    Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
    Title = "Update Est. Close Date",
    Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
    Text = "Update Est. Close Date"
});
```

When i click on the button, bot echoes back with "Update button" text in Microsoft Teams desktop versoin. But that is not the case for Microsoft Team in iOS. Is this an issue with MessageBack action type in Microsoft Teams? Please help.

If you see below when user clicks on "Update Est. Close Date", i see an echo of the same text from Bot to User, in Microsoft Teams application in PC, but not in iOS.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A messageBack button has an additional property that you're not using here - `displayText`. That is what's echoed back to the user in the chat/channel to let them know that the button was pressed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/teams-bots-cards#messageback) for more information.

I think you've found a small difference in the web/desktop and iOS clients with respect to what happens if the `displayText` property is *not* present, but messageBack definitely works on all Teams clients.

Comment: For my scenario, i dont want to echo back what user has clicked. Thats the reason i am not using "displaytext". So "Update Est.Close Date" should not be shown in channel. This is working fine in MS Teams in iOS, but not in Windows PC. I am not sure if i am missing anything here, or its an issue with MS Teams.

Comment: Then what do you want to appear to the user? That's what .displayText is for.

Comment: I dont want the text to echo back to user, hence i am not setting displayText. But still the text is echoed back. That is the issue i am talking about.

Comment: @bill_bliss can you please comment

Comment: What happens if you set displayText to "" (empty string)?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT how can I catch the Action that was clicked? I Have a question with two options, using `ActionTypes.MessageBack`, but I don't know what I need to write for the Value parameter or if I need to use `context.Wait(what???)` so when the user click something that method is called. How does MessageBack work?