# DisplayText not being echoed back in Microsoft Teams when Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

This question is related to [Issue with ActionTypes.MessageBack in Microsoft Teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152726/issue-with-actiontypes-messageback-in-microsoft-teams). I'm providing the additional steps that we have tried as suggested.

I am using 3.11 version of Bot Builder with C#. I have an action button of type ActionTypes.MessageBack with below attributes

```
`cardActions.Add(new CardAction()
{
    Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
    Title = "Update Est. Close Date",
    Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
    Text = "Update Est. Close Date",
    DisplayText = "I want the user to see this!"
});`
```

When I click on the button, bot echoes back with the Text property in Microsoft Teams desktop version. But that is not the case for Microsoft Teams in iOS. Is this an issue with MessageBack action type in Microsoft Teams? Please help.

If you see below when user clicks on "Update Est. Close Date", I see an echo of the same text from Bot to User, in Microsoft Teams application in PC, but not in iOS.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZWvC.png)

Comment: Use `ActionTypes.ImBack` instead